# Why in Beresheit 2:2 (and Kidush) we switch between מְלַאכְתּ֖וֹ and מִכׇּל־מְלַאכְתּ֖וֹ?

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, creation, kiddush

I've always had this question regarding the pasuk in Beresheit 2:2 which which we also say at kidush which says,

"וַיְכַ֤ל אֱלֹהִים֙ בַּיּ֣וֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִ֔י **מְלַאכְתּ֖וֹ** אֲשֶׁ֣ר עָשָׂ֑ה וַיִּשְׁבֹּת֙ בַּיּ֣וֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִ֔י **מִכׇּל־מְלַאכְתּ֖וֹ** אֲשֶׁ֥ר עָשָֽׂה׃"

"On the seventh day God finished **the work** that had been undertaken: [God] ceased on the seventh day from doing **any** of the work."

My question is, why does the pasuk switch from מְלַאכְתּ֖וֹ, that Hashem rested from His melacha, and then after it says **מִכׇּל**־מְלַאכְתּ֖וֹ, from **all** His melacha? Why not say for both of them מְלַאכְתּ֖וֹ or for both of them מִכׇּל־מְלַאכְתּ֖וֹ?

Would appreciate any answers, thanks!

Comment: grammatically, wouldn't the second version have to be "mimlachto" FROM his work? Also, the Ibn Ezra there seems to say that the first part refers to the ceasing on the seventh of the work done on the 6th then the statement that the resting is from ALL the work down through the week? https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.2.2?lang=bi&with=Ibn%20Ezra&lang2=en

Answer (score 3):

Great question. I think Rashi gives two answers to what is the  ויכל אלקים ביום השביעי which answer your question.

> And God completed on the seventh day: Rabbi Shimon said: [A human
> being of] flesh and blood, who cannot [exactly] know his times and his
> moments, must add from the profane to the holy [i.e., he must add some
> time to the Sabbath.] The Holy One, blessed be He, Who knows His times
> and His moments [exactly], entered it [the Sabbath] within a
> hairbreadth, and it therefore appeared as if He completed it [His
> work] on that day. Another explanation: What was the world lacking?
> Rest. The Sabbath came, and so came rest. The work was completed and
> finished. — [from Gen. Rabbah 10:9]
>
> וַיְכַל אֱלֹהִים בַּיּוֹם הַשְּׁבִיעִי: ר' שִׁמְעוֹן אוֹמֵר בָּשָׂר
> וָדָם, שֶׁאֵינוֹ יוֹדֵעַ עִתָּיו וּרְגָעָיו צָרִיך לְהוֹסִיף מֵחֹל עַל
> הַקֹּדֶשׁ, הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא שֶׁיּוֹדֵעַ עִתָּיו וּרְגָעָיו,
> נִכְנָס בֹּו כְּחוּט הַשַּׂעֲרָה, וְנִרְאֶה כְאִלּוּ כִלָּה בוֹ
> בַיֹּום. דָּבָר אַחֵר מֶה הָיָה הָעוֹלָם חָסֵר? מְנוּחָה, בָּאת
> שַׁבָּת בָּאת מְנוּחָה, כָּלְתָה וְנִגְמְרָה הַמְּלָאכָה:[[1]](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8166/showrashi/true/jewish/Chapter-2.htm)

Answer #1 the first מלאכתו is in reference to the מלאכה that was just done has been immediately ceased, but the second is that no מלאכה of any kind was done from then on either.

Answer #2 one cessation is in reference to the previous work and one cessation is in reference to "creating" מנוחה

Although I don't think the אור החיים הקדוש is saying the exact same thing, he does make mention of the nuance between different forms of creation. Like what was just being done just before shabbos and all the other creation that was done during the full six days. I personally see this implied by Rashi and his divrei hamaskil, but certainly can be argued with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I liked answer 2, but I have a question regarding the Or HaChaim and answer 1 approach: Why couldn't the Torah just have one phrase for the melacha that was just done and melacha that was done from then on?

Comment: @AvishaiTebeka The Ohr HaChaim speaks of a specific act of creation done on the Eve of Shabbos. That Hashem didn't complete an act of creation he was in the "middle" of and also that he didn't do another act of creation. He understand that the first mention of cessation of Melacha is to not do another act (ie: start something new on Shabbos) and the מכל מלאכתו is that Hashem stopped even in the middle of an act of creation. He of course could have finished it instantly but did this intentionally to show and honour the greatness of shabbos.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: No problem, My pleasure. It was a great question.